# Why is my :after pseudoelement content not working?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use the `:after` pseudo element to change the text of my button. From the docs I've read `input` is a valid tag for it, and I've got the `content` property which is obviously required here, but the value of the button is not changed as expected. What am I missing?

```css
input {
  width: 200px;
}

input[type=submit] {
  color: red;
}

input[type=submit]:after {
  content: 'next';
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="my button" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/phantom42/pen/OJrqzzN)